# webBrowser_ProgressChanged giving negative output for progressBar

Tags: c#, browser, progress

I'm trying to complete a simple progressbar to my web browser control, but can't understand why I'm getting the following error:

> "Value of '-1' is not valid for 'Value'. 'Value' should be between
>   'minimum' and 'maximum'. Parameter name: Value"

I'm not sure how the progress is returning a -1.

Here's the code I currently have tried:

```
    private void webBrowser1_ProgressChanged(object sender, WebBrowserProgressChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        int max = (int)e.MaximumProgress;
        int current = (int)e.CurrentProgress;
        int min = 0;

        progressBar1.Minimum = 0;
        progressBar1.Maximum = max;
        progressBar1.Value = current;
    }
```

Is anyone able to see where I might be going wrong?

Comment: [WebBrowserProgressChangedEventArgs.CurrentProgress](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowserprogresschangedeventargs.currentprogress%28v=vs.110%29.aspx): "*The number of bytes that have been loaded or -1 to indicate that the download has completed.*" Documentation is your friend.

Comment: @J.Steen Ok, so would it be logical if I added this right after declaring the values: `if (current == -1){current = max;}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you read the documentation about what [WebBrowserProgressChangedEventArgs.CurrentProgress](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowserprogresschangedeventargs.currentprogress%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) will contain, it says that it's

> "The number of bytes that have been loaded or -1 to indicate that the download has completed."

So, it'd be logical to assume that when you get a value of -1, your progressbar should be completed - or hidden, however you want to handle it.